# input Width in Chrome и FireFox

Tags: html, css

Скажите почему вот этот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/hs3bspau/) в консоли разработчика показывает в Chrome 136px,
а при наведении на элемент в консоли Firefox - 138px

**HTML**

```
<input type="text">
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  display: block;
  width: 130px;
  height: 45px;
  outline: none;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, разобрался reset.css, интересно почему в reset.css, взятого [отсюда](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) нет сброса стилей input

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы.